# Set a gradient background

Tags: android

In my Activity I need to change an ImageView background using a gradient, so I use an image with a transparent area, changing its background when I need. Here's some code:

```
private static View myImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myActivityLayout);

    myImage = findViewById(R.id.myImageID);
}
```

[...]

```
private void myImageUpdate() {
    GradientDrawable gradient;
    int[] colors = {0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF};

    // I make some changes to these colors..

    gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, colors);
    myImage.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
}
```

Now, the problem is:
If I call myImageUpdate() within onCreate() method, everything works fine.
If I call myImageUpdate() from another part of the code (like an onClick callback), I can't set my backgroud!

*** UPDATE ***
Guys, this code is fine... I was calling my method in a wrong (not directly reachable) line! My apologies...

Comment: what is the indicator object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will fix it since you said myImageUpdate gets called within onClick... but try this..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            myImage.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
            }
          });
```

you might have to make gradient variable final..

```
   final GradientDrawable  gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try myImage.invalidate(). This will force the system to redraw the view.